# Which openMP pragma do I use for a blocking for loop?

Tags: c++, openmp

My algorithm (solving Poisson's equation) is completely parallelizable--provided that all the threads sync at the end of each iteration.

```
Function f, fNext;
init(f);
#pragma omp parallel
for(int step=0; step<maxITER; step++) {
#pragma omp for
   for(int i=0; i<N; i++) {
      for(int j=0; j<N; j++) {
         fNext(i,j) = someOperator( f(i,j) );
      }
   }
   f = fNext;
}//Threads must synchronize here
```

Does `#pragma omp for` ensure thread synchronization before continuing to the next iteration?

Comment: your `i` for loop will be split to threads, and each of them will run its own `j` loop. Maybe you can have a look at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sz9sd6et(v=vs.80).aspx

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes.   From the [OpenMP Spec](http://www.openmp.org/mp-documents/OpenMP3.1.pdf) (eg, v 3.1, but this has been in since the beginning), under "worksharing constructs:"

> There is an implicit barrier at the end of a loop construct unless
>   a nowait clause is specified.

That is, at the end of the for loop, unless you do something like `#pragma omp for nowait`, there is an implied barrier so that no thread will execute `f=fNext` until all threads are done the for loop.